# I need to enable AutoAdminLogon for windows server 2003 on an amazon vm instance

Tags: windows, login

I'm trying to do something similar to this linked question:
[Configuring Windows Server 2003 to start the administrator account even with no session?](https://serverfault.com/q/92342)

I'm starting an amazon instance of a windows 2003 vm, and I need the AutoAdminLogon to work.

I've set DefaultUsername, DefaultPassword, AutoAdminLogon and even tried ForceAutoLogon.

I basically followed this to the T:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231

No dice with the auto login actually working.  Does anyone know what would prevent it from working?

thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you need the server to auto login?

Comment: Hi Pablo, I'm establishing a VNC connection to the server, but I require that once the VNC connection is established for there to be a desktop, not a login screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is never a good idea. If you need some application to start when the server does (which is what I feel like you are trying to do here), try turning your EXE into a service: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: I appreciate your concern on whether or not it's a good idea.  I need the functionality provided by Microsoft that I mentioned above to work.